# Formatting page number for appendices MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I'm trying to number my appendices with a letter and page number, so for example, A1-A16 for Appendix A, and then B1-B5 for Appendix B and so on. I also want these values to be reflected in my table of contents (TOC) such that they can be updated.

This is what my final TOC should look like:
[image: TOC Sample screenshot]

Right now, my document has section breaks as shown in the sample. But i'm not sure how to proceed from here in terms of page number formatting.

Comment: [How to number chapters, appendixes, and pages in documents that contain both chapter and appendix headings in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-number-chapters-appendixes-and-pages-in-documents-that-contain-both-chapter-and-appendix-headings-in-word-2d9a939c-2863-45c3-bf5e-74b32972035d)

Comment: Word MVP Shauna Kelly's page: http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html

Answer (score 0):

### Word does not have a Table of Contents (TOC) format for Pages x-y.

It shows the beginning page but not the ending. There is no built-in method of doing this.

To do this, you would need to manually edit the TOC in your final draft. *Each time the TOC is updated, it will lose the last page information for your sections.*

You could include the information in your headings using the [Page field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/aef4b341-db2a-4bd9-9f97-2d3b97a89b67) and [SectionPages field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/66f025dd-bc6c-4391-b223-886da61b8ade).  If in the heading itself, it will appear. That would update with the TOC automatically. You would then want to omit the page number from the TOC field itself for those levels.

See also

- Word MVP Shauna Kelly's [Numbering Appendices in Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html)
- Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm).